# Run Cleanup Phase when a test phase job fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, build-automation, ready-api

I have 2 phases in Jenkins Multijob project. One Cleanup Phase and Other Phase has 4 Test Jobs to run sequentially.

My Question is when one of the 4 Test job fails, I would like to run Clean Up Phase and then re-run the failed Job.

Can this be done on Jenkins?

Comment: please consider switching to Jenkins Pipeline (MultiJob not supporting Pipeline yet and will probably won't support it) with 'parallel' steps. If you still want this in MultiJob, open an issue for it in https://github.com/jenkinsci/tikal-multijob-plugin/issues

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve what you want with jenkins pipeline. I've provided example below with 3 test jobs:

```
node{
    def results = new String[3]
    stage("Run tests"){
        for(int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            // Run tests and store results (SUCCESS, FAILURE, etc.) in array
            results[i-1] = build(job: "TEST_JOB_$i", propagate: false).result
        }
        // If at least one test failed
        if("FAILURE" in results)
        {
            build job: 'CLEANUP_JOB', propagate: false
            for(int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
                if(results[i-1] == "FAILURE")
                {
                    // If this job fails now, then current build ends with failure
                    build(job: "TEST_JOB_$i", propagate: true)   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"propagate: false" causes rest of the pipeline to run even if the build fails. It's possible to achieve something similiar with Multijob plugin, but it would be very ugly.